# How to share rte_keepalive across different applications?

Tags: dpdk

In the [DPDK Keep Alive Sample Application](https://dpdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sample_app_ug/keep_alive.html), each slave core accesses the global `rte_global_keepalive_info` to mark itself as still alive.

Consider the case when you have a master application that uses core 1, and a slave application that uses core 2. The master application needs to regularly check if the slave application is still alive. So the master creates `rte_global_keepalive_info` and expects that the slave will regularly call [rte_keepalive_mark_alive()](http://dpdk.org/doc/api/rte__keepalive_8h.html#a960d89839629472d7f34d453314a2782) using this variable.

If, however, the master and slave applications cannot share global variables as they are distinct processes with separate memory allocations, how is it possible for the slave application to "mark alive" the `rte_global_keepalive_info` created by the master application? Should the master still use [rte_keepalive_create()](http://dpdk.org/doc/api/rte__keepalive_8h.html#af8499cadbfb5ecb632f7c8fe0da4281e) to create the `rte_global_keepalive_info` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, both processes should use some form of Inter Process Communication, for example, use a shared memory with shm_open(3)

There is an example for that, please have a look at [keepalive shared memory management](http://dpdk.org/doc/api/examples_2l2fwd-keepalive_2shm_8c-example.html)
and
[keepalive Agent example](http://dpdk.org/doc/api/examples_2l2fwd-keepalive_2ka-agent_2main_8c-example.html)